# Facebook API for iPhone Error: An active access token must be used

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to retrieve my online friends and I am getting this error:

> "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

This is my method:

```
-(IBAction)act:(id)sender{

    NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"user_online_presence", @"friends_online_presence", nil] retain];
    
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];     
   
    NSLog(@"dd");
    NSLog(@"%@",facebook.accessToken);
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not waiting for the authorization to complete.

You will need to implement the didLogin delegate method, and

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

should go only after didLogin was called.

Comment: how is the structure of didlogin? for example for didfailwitherror is this one: - (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didFailWithError:(id)result {

Comment: -(void)fbDidLogin;
And it's on FBSessionDelegate (who's also in Facebook.h)

Comment: I have tried this one on my .m but is not working! I am using the last version of FBconnect. -(void)fbDidLogin{
    
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];     
    NSLog(@"did login");

}

Comment: It works for me
Looking back at your code, you are using
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self]

in my code i have
[facebook authorize:my_facebook_app_id permissions:permissions delegate:self]

Do you provide your facebook app id elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah! The pop up window ask me if I want to authorize and blah blah. Everything works fine except this! Here is my app id:- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxxxxxxx"];
    [facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];

Comment: Something i forgot to mention is that I am doing all these procedures in my appViewController.m! Is ok with that right?

Comment: It should, you can also implement -(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled to check if it falls there.