# Facebook SDK + iPhone SDK + SSO

Tags: iphone, facebook, single-sign-on

I know that this question has been asked, but I have been reading through threads all day and have applied all of the fixes I could find and am still having an issue.

I am trying to implement Facebook SDK's new SSO feature to allow my app to authenticate with Facebook's app instead of a webView. When my app switches to Facebook's app, it says loading for a few seconds and switches back but the token is still null. I have a feeling it has to do with the URL scheme for my app but I have followed many tutorials and am fairly confident that my current plist values are correct:
[image]

Here is the code I have implemented in my appDelegate and viewController files:
appDelegate.h

```
Facebook *facebook;
```

appDelegate.m

```
// Pre 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

// For 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
-(IBAction) fbButton {
    //FACEBOOK INTEGRATION
    appDelegate.facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"222087841143437" andDelegate:appDelegate];

    // Check and retrieve authorization information
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        appDelegate.facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        appDelegate.facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
    if (![appDelegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        appDelegate.facebook.sessionDelegate = self;
        [appDelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];
        NSLog(@"Token: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Already logged in!");

    }
    [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];

}


- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSString *nameID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", [result objectForKey:@"name"], [result objectForKey:@"id"]];
    NSMutableArray *userData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [result objectForKey:@"id"], @"id", 
                                 nameID, @"name", 
                                 [result objectForKey:@"picture"], @"details", 
                                 nil], nil];

    [userData release];
    [nameID release];
    NSLog(@"DATA RECEIVED: %@", result);
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"request:didReceiveResponse:");
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Err details: %@", [error description]);
};
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[[appDelegate facebook] accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[[appDelegate facebook] expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Facebook Logged in!");

    [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];


}
```

I know that I call [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self] twice, but I don't think that's the problem.

Here is a snippet from the console when I press the login button:

```
2011-10-18 15:37:33.287 Track[2235:707] Token: (null)
2011-10-18 15:37:36.578 Track[2235:707] request:didReceiveResponse:
2011-10-18 15:37:36.584 Track[2235:707] The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)
2011-10-18 15:37:36.586 Track[2235:707] Err details: Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x1ce480 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x1c9560 [0x3e368630]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x19a830 [0x3e368630]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x11d230 [0x3e368630]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x1f5b60 [0x3e368630]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x1f8a70 [0x3e368630]>{contents = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}
```

I appreciate the help and I really hope I didn't miss a discussion on here that solves this problem. Here are a few (of the many) that I have read through and had no success in finding a solution

[How to implement Single Sign On (SSO) using facebook ios sdk for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786819/how-to-implement-single-sign-on-sso-using-facebook-ios-sdk-for-iphone)
[Facebook SSO and request iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151737/facebook-sso-and-request-ios-sdk)
[Facebook API for iPhone Error: An active access token must be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117622/facebook-api-for-iphone-error-an-active-access-token-must-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Facebook application (the actual application that you created on Facebook) is not in sandbox mode and if it is make sure that the user your Facebook application (the iPhone Facebook client) is currently logged in with is a developer for that application.

Comment: I just checked and the application is NOT in sandbox mode, and I am definitely a developer for that application. It seems more like a problem with my app not reading in the information passed back from the Facebook app itself

Comment: The reason that I've suggested that is that from what you say Facebook is redirecting you back to your application seconds after switching to it. As far as I know the normal flow would ask you to accept the required permissions or hit OK if you've already accepted them before. Try removing the Facebook application (see under Privacy settings -> Apps and Websites) from your user profile and run you app again. As I said Facebook shouldn't switch back to your app without any kind of input from you...